# How to pad text in bash

Tags: bash

I want to create a text file using bash shell in the following

```
+9990000001
+9990000002
+9990000003
+9990000004
...
```

The first four chars/digits are fixed (+999) and the other 7 digits starts from 0000001 to 9999999

I have the following code but it does not do 00000000 padding.

```
startnum=0;
endnum=9999999;

for (( i=$startnum; i<=$endnum; i++ )) ; do 
echo $i ;
done
```

How would I also do the prefix +999?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `printf` to pad `0s`:

```
startnum=1
endnum=9999999

for (( i=startnum; i<=endnum; i++ )) ; do 
  printf "+999%07d\n" $i
done
```

**Output:**

```
+9990000001
+9990000002
+9990000003
+9990000004
+9990000005
+9990000006
...
```

Comment: For @user2135737, additional suggestion made in the edit was that when you use `(( ... ))` that is arithmetic context, you don't really need to put `$` sigil in front of variables. Also, the `;` delimiter is only useful when you write the entire script in one line. When you separate them with newlines, they become superfluous. Having both doesn't hurt but you can save some keystrokes in avoiding them.

Comment: thanks guys! I threw the output into a text file using > redirector. Saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
startnum=90000000
endnum=99999999

for (( i = startnum; i <= endnum; i++ )) ; do 
    echo +99$i
done
```

(I *would* have suggested simply putting all three nines at the beginning, but 10<sup>10</sup>−1 is outside the range of 32-bit signed integers, so I'm not sure the arithmetic part would work.)

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
seq -f "+%10.0f" 9990000001 9999999999
```

or

```
seq -f "+999%07.0f" 9999999
```